# Apache Royale : how to show Handcursor over Jewel Label?

Tags: mouse-cursor, apache-royale

Is there a way to show Handcursor when mouse go over a `j:Label` ?

(equivalent of buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" ).

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `className="cursor-pointer"`. From Tour de Jewel examples:

```xml
<j:Label localId="label" text="This is a Label" click="labelClick(event)" className="cursor-pointer">
    <j:beads>
        <j:ToolTip toolTip="This Label is clickable!"/>
    </j:beads>
</j:Label>
```